# How to jump some steps when use python's for statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an interveiw yesterday, when I write python code to achieve some algorithm, I have a question. Some logic can be achieved like this using C:

```
void get_some_num(int a[], int length) {       
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < length - 1; ++i) {
       if(something) i++; // jump a num in the array
       a[i] = 1;
   }
    return some_num;
 }
```

C language can jump some elements(such as n) when using `i += n` statement in for-loop to iterate an array, but I find it's difficult to achieve by using python's for statement gracefully.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by `jump some steps in for loop`? Also, python has `continue`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget like C language's `i += n` in for loop.

Comment: Check `xrange` if the steps are regular. If you want to do something wild, implement your own iterator or use `while`. That said, your question is very vague; if you want a better answer, you should write precisely what it is you want to do.

Comment: @Amadan I have try my best to describe the quesion, and I have changed the description, could you understand it now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do this in a way similar to `C`, then just use a `while` loop (any `for` loop is really just a specialization of a `while` loop after all):

```
i = 0
end = 10

while i < end:
    # NOTE: do something with i here

    if i == 5:
        i += 3
    i += 1
```

Or you can explicitly create and move forward the iterator (which I find a lot less readable):

```
it = iter(range(0, 10))

for i in it:
    if i == 5:
        for j in range(0, 3):
            i = next(it)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 7):

Python also supports continue to "skip steps" and continue the loop.

Using it in a for loop:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if i == 5:
        continue
    # will never print 5
    print(i)
```

if you are looking to make it skip a few indexes in your iteration, then you can do something like this with a while loop:

```
x = range(0, 10)
i = 0
while i <= len(x):
    if i == 5:
        i += 3
        continue
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault to put it vaguely, I just want to jump some elements using for statement. But it's difficult to achieve by using python's for. But `while` can achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never really had much need to skip more than one step, but...  You can use a `skip` variable that you decrement every time you skip.

```
skip = 0
for i, item in enumerate(my_list[:-1]):
    if skip:
        skip -= 1
        continue
    if item == my_list[i+1]:
        skip = 1   # or whatever n value you want
        continue
    # Other code
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do several jumps use the mod operator **%**

i.e

Jump every 2

```
for i in range(1, 10):
if i%2 == 0:
    print(i)
```

2
4
6
8

jump every 3

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    if i%3 == 0:
        print(i)
```

3
6
9

An so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `continue`

```
for item in loop:
    if item == 'wrong':
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `range()` function allows three arguments- `start`, `stop`, and `step`.

You can 'jump some steps' by changing the value of `step` to something other than 1. By default, it is 1, when not anything is passed.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), this is how it looks like:

```py
class range(stop)
class range(start, stop, step=1)
```

And it will work like this:

```py
>>> for i in range(5): # starts from 0, by default, with step=1
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for i in range(1, 5): # unless you give it a specific start
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
>>> for i in range(0, 500, 100): # here, step=100
...     print(i)
...
0
100
200
300
400
>>> for i in range(500, 100): # but, passing step, requires start
...     print(i)
...
>>>
```